# Passing data between components and use the ngDocheck

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

We are trying to pass data from one component to another and below is the approach we are taking. When there is no data we want to show the error message and if there is data we show that in the select box.

```
showGlobalError = true;

constructor(
  private psService: ProjectShipmentService, 
  private pdComp: ProjectDetailsComponent
) {
    this.psService.tDate.subscribe(x => this.cachedResults = x);
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.cachedResults.length > 0 && this.count <= 1) {
        this.showGlobalError = false;
        this.populateArrays();
        this.count++;
      }
  }    

  populateArrays() {
    this.reportingProject = [this.pdComp.rProjectNumber];
    this.projectSalesOrder = this.pdComp.rSalesOrder;
    this.clearFilter();
    //  ........
```

Our HTML looks like below:

```
<div *ngIf="showGlobalError">
  <h6>The reporting project doesn't have any Shippable Items</h6>
</div>
<div id="search-block" class="box-shadow-block">
   <span>Reporting Project</span>
   <dx-select-box
     [items]="reportingProject"
     [text]="reportingProject"
     [readOnly]="true"
     >
   </dx-select-box>
</div>
```

The issue is The Reporting Project number appears in the select box but when I click on the select box and click anywhere else in the page the project number disappears. I am not sure if this has something to do with the ngDoCheck(). Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

set first your showGlobalError to false and do the logic in your ngOnInit.

```
showGlobalError = false;
```

in your view:

```
<div *ngIf="showGlobalError">
  <h6>The reporting project doesn't have any Shippable Items</h6>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!showGlobalError" id="search-block" class="box-shadow-block">
   <span>Reporting Project</span>
   <dx-select-box
     [items]="reportingProject"
     [text]="reportingProject"
     [readOnly]="true"
     >
   </dx-select-box>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code to get data from service.

```
this.psService.tDate.subscribe(x => {this.cachedResults = x},
    (err) => {},
    () => {this.checkForCachedResults()}
);
```

and write function to execute your conditional check instead of doCheck() like follows

```
checkForCachedResults() {
    if (this.cachedResults.length > 0 && this.count <= 1) {
        this.showGlobalError = false;
        this.populateArrays();
        this.count++;
    }
}
```